# Mедиа запрос и position: fixed

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

При медиа запросе на мобильном  устройстве, всплывающие окно никак не реагирует на изменения. Не знаю как исправить ошибку.
 Подскажите. Вот код:

```js
function myBtn() {
  document.getElementById('modalW').style.display = 'block';
}

function closee() {
  document.getElementById('modalW').style.display = 'none';
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == document.getElementById('modalW')) {
    document.getElementById('modalW').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
/*Smartphones*/

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .modalW {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    top: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  }
  .modalW__text p {
    font-size: 32px;
  }
}

.modalOne {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.modalW {
  margin: 4% auto;
  width: 528px;
  height: 533px;
  background: #f8f9fa;
  padding: 0px 41px 10px 41px;
  /*z-index: 9999;*/
}

.modalW__text p {
  font-family: Bello-Pro;
  font-size: 64px;
  color: #263238;
  margin: 0px;
}

.modalW__text i {
  color: #9C27B0;
  position: relative;
  left: 470px;
  top: -1px;
}

form {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  /*position: relative;
        bottom: 20px;*/
}

form p {
  font-family: Roboto-Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

.text {
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border-color: #95BB31;
  padding-right: 17px;
  width: 211px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-style: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #95BB31;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: Roboto-Bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #263238;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

.lobel__name {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  right: 186px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.lobel__phone {
  position: relative;
  left: 60px;
  bottom: 17px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.lobel span {
  color: red;
}

#text {
  margin-right: 17px;
}

.lobel__message {
  text-align: left;
}

#message {
  width: 465px;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  outline: 2px solid #95BB31;
  border-style: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.control__text {
  position: relative;
  left: 6px;
  bottom: -7px;
  font-family: Roboto-Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

.control {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 37px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.control input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.control_indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  left: 0;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  background: #f8f9fa;
  border: 2px solid #95BB31;
}

.control-radio .control_indicator {
  border-radius: undefined%;
}

.control:hover input~.control_indicator,
.control input:focus~.control_indicator {
  background: #f8f9fa;
}

.control input:checked~.control_indicator {
  background: #f8f9fa;
}

.control:hover input:not([disabled]):checked~.control_indicator,
.control input:checked:focus~.control_indicator {
  background: #f8f9fa;
}

.control input:disabled~.control_indicator {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.control_indicator:after {
  box-sizing: unset;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.control input:checked~.control_indicator:after {
  display: block;
}

.control-checkbox .control_indicator:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 6px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 8px;
  border: solid #9C27B0;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.control-checkbox input:disabled~.control_indicator:after {
  border-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.modal__recap img {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.modal__recap button {
  border: none;
  background: #9C27B0;
  font-family: Roboto-Bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 12px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 32px;
  left: 75px;
  background: #9C27B0;
  box-shadow: 10px 15px 30px 0 rgba(150, 26, 129, 0.36);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myBtn()">Связаться с нами</button>
<div class="modalOne" id="modalW">
  <div class="modalW">
    <div class="modalW__text">
      <span onclick="closee()">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       </span>
      <p>Напишите нам</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal__form">
      <form>
        <div class="lobel">
          <p class="lobel__name">Ваше имя <span>*</span></p>
          <p class="lobel__phone">Ваш телефон <span>*</span></p>
        </div>
        <input class="text" id="text" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Иван Иванов">
        <input class="text" type="text" name="" placeholder="+7 (___) ___ __ __">
        <p class="lobel__message">Ваше сообщение</p>
        <input class="text" id="message" type="text" name="" placeholder="Ваше сообщение">
      </form>
      <label class="control control-checkbox">
               <p class="control__text">Согласен с обработкой моих персональных данных в соответствии с политикой конфиденциальности</p> 
                <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
                <div class="control_indicator" id="control"></div>
            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="modal__recap">
      <img src="img/recaptcha2.png">
      <button onclick="resultClick()">Отправить</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @ Максим, конечно он там есть. я уже три страницы сверстала адаптивно, а тут дело дошло до модального окна и ничего не работает((

Comment: @ Максим, спасибо, но не помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Комментарии в коде, что было изменено...

```js
function myBtn() {
  document.getElementById('modalW').style.display = 'block';
}

function closee() {
  document.getElementById('modalW').style.display = 'none';
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == document.getElementById('modalW')) {
    document.getElementById('modalW').style.display = 'none';
  }
}

document.getElementById('modalW').style.display = 'none'; //добавленая строка
```

```css
/*Smartphones*/

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) and (min-width:320px) {
  /*медия любит точное определение элемента*/
  /*надо прописывать вложености*/
  .modalOne>.modalW {
    /*display: none; убери отсюда эту строку и добавь ее в JS*/
    position: relative;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    top: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    background: #1fc1fc;
  }
  .modalOne>.modalW>.modalW__text>p {
    font-size: 32px;
  }
}

.modalOne {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.modalW {
  margin: 4% auto;
  width: 528px;
  height: 533px;
  background: #f8f9fa;
}

.modalW__text p {
  font-family: Bello-Pro;
  font-size: 64px;
  color: #263238;
  margin: 0px;
}

.modalW__text i {
  color: #9C27B0;
  position: relative;
  left: 470px;
  top: -1px;
}

form {
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  /*position: relative;
        bottom: 20px;*/
}

form p {
  font-family: Roboto-Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

.text {
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  border-color: #95BB31;
  padding-right: 17px;
  width: 211px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-style: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #95BB31;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-family: Roboto-Bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #263238;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

.lobel__name {
  position: relative;
  top: 4px;
  right: 186px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.lobel__phone {
  position: relative;
  left: 60px;
  bottom: 17px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.lobel span {
  color: red;
}

#text {
  margin-right: 17px;
}

.lobel__message {
  text-align: left;
}

#message {
  width: 465px;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  outline: 2px solid #95BB31;
  border-style: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.control__text {
  position: relative;
  left: 6px;
  bottom: -7px;
  font-family: Roboto-Regular;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

.control {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 37px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.control input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.control_indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  left: 0;
  height: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  background: #f8f9fa;
  border: 2px solid #95BB31;
}

.control-radio .control_indicator {
  border-radius: undefined%;
}

.control:hover input~.control_indicator,
.control input:focus~.control_indicator {
  background: #f8f9fa;
}

.control input:checked~.control_indicator {
  background: #f8f9fa;
}

.control:hover input:not([disabled]):checked~.control_indicator,
.control input:checked:focus~.control_indicator {
  background: #f8f9fa;
}

.control input:disabled~.control_indicator {
  background: #e6e6e6;
  opacity: 0.6;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.control_indicator:after {
  box-sizing: unset;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.control input:checked~.control_indicator:after {
  display: block;
}

.control-checkbox .control_indicator:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 6px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 8px;
  border: solid #9C27B0;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.control-checkbox input:disabled~.control_indicator:after {
  border-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.modal__recap img {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.modal__recap button {
  border: none;
  background: #9C27B0;
  font-family: Roboto-Bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 12px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 32px;
  left: 75px;
  background: #9C27B0;
  box-shadow: 10px 15px 30px 0 rgba(150, 26, 129, 0.36);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myBtn()">Связаться с нами</button>
<div class="modalOne" id="modalW">
  <div class="modalW">
    <div class="modalW__text">
      <span onclick="closee()">
                    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
      <p>Напишите нам</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal__form">
      <form>
        <div class="lobel">
          <p class="lobel__name">Ваше имя <span>*</span></p>
          <p class="lobel__phone">Ваш телефон <span>*</span></p>
        </div>
        <input class="text" id="text" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Иван Иванов">
        <input class="text" type="text" name="" placeholder="+7 (___) ___ __ __">
        <p class="lobel__message">Ваше сообщение</p>
        <input class="text" id="message" type="text" name="" placeholder="Ваше сообщение">
      </form>
      <label class="control control-checkbox">
                        <p class="control__text">Согласен с обработкой моих персональных данных в соответствии с политикой конфиденциальности</p>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="check" />
                        <div class="control_indicator" id="control"></div>
                    </label>
    </div>
    <div class="modal__recap">
      <img src="img/recaptcha2.png">
      <button onclick="resultClick()">Отправить</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen
and (min-device-width: 320px)
and (max-device-width: 480px) {
```

замени на

```
@media(max-width: 480px)
```

прикол в том, что ты обращаешься к device-width. Например у iphone 4 ширина 640px, но тк у них 2пикселя на 1 css пиксель, то получается 320, но device-width будет обращаться как раз к 640, отсюда и косяк