# Резиновая верстка при уменьшение экрана

Tags: css, media-queries

Вот тут на [Сайте](https://vivisa.github.io/ViViSa.github.io-orli/), блоку меню задала bottom и теперь когда хочу уменьшить экран - меню налазит на блок. Даже предположений нет. Как исправить данную ситуацию + кнопки под меню на месте (опять же при уменьшение экрана). Медиа запросы не реагируют. И там еще картинка в виде шашлыка тоже не правильно. Подскажите как исправить ситуацию.
Сама наверстала теперь страдаю.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Mедиа запрос и position: fixed](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/839697/m%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b8-position-fixed)

Comment: @Air, нет. это разные вещи, то медиа запрос то есть адаптивная верстка, а это резиновая. я сама уменьшая экран, а не выбираю (моб версия, планшет  либо еще какое-то устройство).

Comment: В чем разница, между адаптивной версткой  и резиновой?)))))

Comment: @Air, к адаптивной верстке применяться медиа запросы, а к резиновой - нет

Comment: )))  пусть по твоему...

Comment: @Air, понятна Ваша позиция. тогда почему медиа запросы не реагируют на изменения экрана, только тогда когда я нажму в хроме моб версия и выберу responsive и начну уменьшать экран, только тогда и заработаю эти запросы?

Comment: Ты хотя-бы  выложи сюда пример того, как и что реализовал... Людям гадать? Лично мне ковыряться  по ссылке которую ты прислал, нет вообще желания...

Comment: @Air, Вы хамло.

Comment: Благодарю)))))))